# Authenticate via Service Principal to Azure HTTP Function - No "identity_token" returned with client_credentials flow

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I have an Azure HTTPTriggered Function App that I want to authenticate to and make calls to via a service principal using client_credentials workflow.

If I attempt to hit the endpoint https://myAzureFunction.azurewebsite.net/api/books from a browser, I get redirected and authenticate with my user credentials. I then land on the endpoint and get returned the JSON that I expect.

If I try this via client_credentials workflow in Postman

I get a bearer token via:

Access Token URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/My_Tenant_GUID/oauth2/v2.0/token

Scope:
https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

I then do a **GET** to the endpoint with the Bearer token in my "Authorization" header

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'. \nkid: '[PII is hidden]'. \nExceptions caught:\n '[PII is hidden]'.\ntoken: '[PII is hidden]'."
}
```

If I check the auth endpoint (/.auth/me) when I am authenticated as myself, I can see that I have an "id_token" but the token I get back from the client_credentials flow is an "access_token" maybe?

I guess my ultimate question is, how do you protect an HTTPTrigger Azure Function so that a service principal can authenticate and make API calls to it without an end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) said:

> At this time, Azure App Service and **Azure Functions are only supported by Azure AD v1.0**. They're not supported by the Microsoft identity platform v2.0, which includes Microsoft Authentication Libraries (MSAL).

So, first add app registration to your function. And use service to service calls to [get access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#service-to-service-access-token-request).

```
POST /tenant id/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=appid&client_secret=xxxxxxx&resource=app_id
```

Also, set the app registration redirect url as the URL of your App Service app and append the path `/.auth/login/aad/callback`. For example, `https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`.

Finally, you could access azure function successfully.